# Можно ли парсить OZON через HTTP запросы?

Tags: python, ajax, parse

Знаю, что с помощью Selenium и подобных инструментов можно парсить инфу о товарах на ОЗОНЕ. Сам делал такое. Но потом понял, что например WB легко парсится через HTTP запросы, что быстрее и стабильнее.

С озоном так прокатит? Знает кто-то endpoint-ы какие-нибудь?

Нашел вот что:

[https://www.ozon.ru/api/composer-api.bx/page/json/v2?url={product_uri}](https://www.ozon.ru/api/composer-api.bx/page/json/v2?url=%7Bproduct_uri%7D)
, где

product_uri ~= /product/kofe-v-kapsulah-absolut-drive-amerikano-dlya-kofemashin-dolce-gusto-dolche-gusto-16-kapsul-175525086

ИЛИ

product_uri ~= /product/175525086/

Но возвращает огромный массив информации и которой либо невозможно либо очень сложно достать данные. Может кто подскажет способ...? И можно ли вообще победить озон через HTTP, или только Selenium?

Comment: Плюс когда пытаюсь получить данные по такому адресу из Python получаю 403. А в браузере все ок. В чем причина?